# Change text content with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, element, xmlnode

Although I am able to set a text value inside a node with the code below

```
private static void setPhoneNumber(Document xmlDoc, String phoneNumber) {
    Element root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();     
    Element phoneParent = (Element) root.getElementsByTagName("gl-bus:entityPhoneNumber").item(0);      
    Element phoneElement = (Element) phoneParent.getElementsByTagName("gl-bus:phoneNumber").item(0);    
    phoneElement.setTextContent(phoneNumber);       
}
```

I cannot do the same with XPath because I get null for the node object

```
private static void setPhoneNumber(Document xmlDoc, String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/gl-cor:entityInformation/gl-bus:entityPhoneNumber/gl-bus:phoneNumber", xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        Node node = nodes.item(0);
        node.setTextContent(phoneNumber);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're using the non-namespace-aware method `getElementsByTagName()`, passing it an element name containing a colon, suggests that you're not handling namespaces properly when you parse the XML.  If your XML were parsed in a namespace-aware manner then this shouldn't have worked, but something like

```
String namespace = // the namespace URI bound to the gl-bus prefix in your doc
Element phoneParent = (Element) root.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, "entityPhoneNumber").item(0);
```

would work correctly.  Note that the standard Java `DocumentBuilderFactory` is *not* namespace aware by default, you must call `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the factory before you ask it for a `newDocumentBuilder`.

XPath requires namespace-aware parsing, and if you want to access elements that are in a namespace via XPath then you must supply a `NamespaceContext` to the `XPath` object to tell it what prefix bindings to use - it does not inherit the prefix bindings from the original XML.  Annoyingly there's no default implementation of `NamespaceContext` provided in the core Java library so you either have to write your own or use a third-party implementation such as [Spring's SimpleNamespaceContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.html).  With that:

```
SimpleNamespaceContext ctx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
ctx.bindNamespaceUri("g", namespace); // the same URI as before
ctx.bindNamespaceUri("c", ...); // the namespace bound to gl-cor:
xPath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/c:entityInformation/g:entityPhoneNumber/g:phoneNumber", xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```